# Administrator Permissions Check (aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i make a telegram bot for administrate telegram groups, but this filter just check admin status:

```
import aiogram
import functools
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BoundFilter

class CheckFilter(BoundFilter):
    key = 'is_admin'
    def __init__(self, is_admin):
        self.is_admin = is_admin
    async def check(self, message: types.Message):
       member = await bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)
       return member.is_chat_admin() == self.is_admin
dp.filters_factory.bind(CheckFilter)
```

i need to check administrator permissions. Example: for use command !ban you need to ban users permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, bot_id)` will do the trick.

aiogram [documentation](https://aiogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram/bot.html#aiogram.bot.bot.Bot.get_chat_member) says:

> Returns: Returns a ChatMember object on success

And what Telegram API [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember) says about ChatMember:

> **...**
>
> **can_edit_messages** *Boolean    Optional.* Administrators only. True, if the administrator can edit messages of other users and can pin messages; channels only
>
> **can_delete_messages**   *Boolean    Optional.* Administrators only. True, if the administrator can delete messages of other users
>
> **can_restrict_members**  *Boolean    Optional.* Administrators only. True, if the administrator can restrict, ban or unban chat members
>
> **...**

Here is an example:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['rights'])
async def myrights(message: types.Message):
    member = await bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, TOKEN.split(":")[0])
    for x in member:
        print(x)
```

And its output (on my terminal) when I write `/rights@BOTUSERNAME` on the group:

```
('user', {'id': xxxxxxxxxx, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'xxxxx', 'username': 'xxxxx'})
('status', 'administrator')
('can_be_edited', False)
('can_change_info', True)
('can_delete_messages', True)
('can_invite_users', True)
('can_restrict_members', True)
('can_pin_messages', True)
('can_promote_members', False)
```